# background of container view is gray

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm not sure how this works, but I set this up in IB.

[image]

I'm trying to use this to show a tutorial for my game when it first loads.  The Container is GameViewController that shows my GameScene.  But then I get a gray background where in my storyboard I have a white background.  And then there's white at the bottom where my scroll indicators are.

[image]